# In Linux kernel_ventry macro how is tpidrro_el0 used? and two other questions.. (.align 7 and virtually mapped stack)

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, arm64, memory-alignment, stack-memory

This is code from linux-5.10.0 's arch/arm64/kernel/entry.S and I'm trying to understand  the macro defining interrupt vector. I think this should be a well-known code for people working on Linux. I marked three lines with Q1,Q2 and Q3.

```
    .macro kernel_ventry, el, label, regsize = 64
    .align 7                                                <== Q1
#ifdef CONFIG_UNMAP_KERNEL_AT_EL0
    .if \el == 0
alternative_if ARM64_UNMAP_KERNEL_AT_EL0
    .if \regsize == 64
    mrs x30, tpidrro_el0                                    <== Q2
    msr tpidrro_el0, xzr
    .else
    mov x30, xzr
    .endif
alternative_else_nop_endif
    .endif
#endif

    sub sp, sp, #S_FRAME_SIZE
#ifdef CONFIG_VMAP_STACK
    /*
     * Test whether the SP has overflowed, without corrupting a GPR.
     * Task and IRQ stacks are aligned so that SP & (1 << THREAD_SHIFT)
     * should always be zero.
     */
    add sp, sp, x0          // sp' = sp + x0
    sub x0, sp, x0          // x0' = sp' - x0 = (sp + x0) - x0 = sp
    tbnz    x0, #THREAD_SHIFT, 0f                                       <== Q3
    sub x0, sp, x0          // x0'' = sp' - x0' = (sp + x0) - sp = x0
    sub sp, sp, x0          // sp'' = sp' - x0 = (sp + x0) - x0 = sp
    b   el\()\el\()_\label
```

Q1 : why is it aligning with 7 byte?
Q2 : The armv8 spec says for TPIDRRO_EL0,

> Provides a location where software executing at EL1 or higher can
> store thread identifying information that is visible to software
> executing at EL0, for OS management purposes.

I know \el1 == 0 means this vector is for case of exceptions taking from a lower exception level(ex, el0->el1). (from calling kernel_ventry at line 516 in the entry.S file). x30 is being filled with tpidrro_el0. If it is a function, it will return to the address at x30 but it will return by eret and elr register should be used. I don't know what the tpidrro_el0 register was containing at this time and how it's being used.
Q3 : Here the stack pointer which is not in x0 is being checked. The value of #THREAD_SHIFT is 12 in my case. I've searched about virtually mapped stack (stack in virtually-contiguous but physically not-contiguous memory, linked pages..) Why does it check bit 12 for overflow? The sp uses the lower 12 bits (when page size is 4K) in virtually mapped stack?

Comment: `.align 7` in ARM means align to 2^7 (128 bytes), not align to 7 bytes. Indeed, ARM64 vector table entries are 128 bytes. The SP overflow is detected using bit 12 because as the comment states the stack is always aligned in such a way to have bit 12 set to 0. It doesn't necessarily mean that only the lower 12 bits are used, just that bit 12 is not used.

Comment: It's always better to use `.p2align 7` or `.balign 128` to make the meaning clear; `.align` is one of the other of those, but it varies by ISA and OS.  In this case it must be `.p2align` since 7 isn't a power of 2.